# Multivariable Calculus Volume of Integration Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, spherical-coordinates

I have an integral
$$
\iiint\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}\,}\,{\rm e}^{-\left(x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}\right)}\,
{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}z
$$
The integration region is bounded by the sphere
$\left\{\left(x,y,z\right)\ \ni\ \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}\,}\, < 4\right\}$. I so far have set up the integral in spherical coordinates subsituting the rho in all of the necessary places. The problem I am having is setting up the bounds for the spherical integral. I know that $0<\theta<2\pi$ and $0<\rho<2$ but I am not sure about how I would set up the final integral in terms of $\phi$. Thanks.

Comment: Usually $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi$. Did you try that? Does it cover the whole sphere?

Comment: in polar coordinates, this becomes $4\pi\int_0^4 r^3 e^{-r^2}dr.$ Now use integration by parts etc.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on the parametrization you use to convert Cartesian into spherical coordinates:  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html

If we go with the parametrization $$(x,y,z) = (\rho \cos \theta \sin \phi, \rho \sin \theta \sin \phi, \rho \cos \phi),$$ then we have $$\rho \in [0, \infty), \quad \theta \in [0, 2\pi), \quad \phi \in [0, \pi].$$  But as I pointed out, this is not the only parametrization.  In all cases, you have to look at the mapping itself to get the appropriate intervals for each parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Usually $\phi \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.